# Flex/Spark: How much logic in view? How to clear a TextField as a reaction to a user click or an event?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex-spark

When using Flex with Spark, I have a simple chat window with a `TextInput` to enter your message and a send `Button`.

`TextInput`

- Starts out as `""`
- Should be set to `""` last in the function that handles the message sending
- Should also be set to `""` as a response for `event="myOtherEvent"`

`Button`

- Should only be enabled when the `TextInput`'s `text.length > 0`

At first I thought it was pretty clean to skip binding the text being entered into the `TextInput` to anything in my model and let that logic for button enabling/disabling stay in the view.

I still feel that it's a pretty nice approach *except* for the fact that it isn't a complete solution as it does not clear the `TextInput.text` as a response to receiving `event="myOtherEvent"`.

The MXML for that partial solutions is:

```
<s:TextInput id="chatText" width="100%" height="32" />
<s:Button
  label="Send"
  enabled="{chatText.text.length > 0}"
  click='{model.send(chatText.text); chatText.text=""}'
/>
```

If it wasn't for my event response requirement, how do you feel about that solution?

There is some logic in the `Button`, but just basic setting and checking. I know that it's a good idea to separate logic and presentation, but I thought this was a nice balance.

A *complete solution* I can think of would be to:

- Have a two way binding of `chatText.text` and a property in my model
- And in the set method for that property, I would `dispatchEvent(new Event("updateButton")`
- A function in the same model class would bind to that event. That function would also be read in `enabled="{model.thatFunction()}"` of the `Button`. The function would return `chatTextStringPropertyInModel.length > 0` and thus (by jumping through some hoops) would see to that the send-`Button` is enabled when there is text available for sending.
- The `model.send(chatText.text)` can set `chatTextStringPropertyInModel=""` after sending and as that property is two-way bound with chatText.text the change would be reflected in the UI too.

My questions:

1. How much logic is all right to have in the view?
2. How should I solve this? What is most elegant and maintainable?

Comment: There's no definitive answer to your question. There are a handful of design patterns you can use. When I was doing Flex, I preferred the [Presentation Model](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/PresentationModel.html). I also used the [Mediator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) in a project or two. These patterns enforce the separation of presentation and logic. A major benefit of this is that it's much easier to test the logic in a unit test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm confused but I don't see an issue in your solution. You just need to add an event handler for your other event

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        //clear text and disable button on other event
        private function onMyOtherEvent(event:Event):void
        {
            chatText.text = "";
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:TextInput id="chatText" width="100%" height="32" />
<s:Button
  label="Send"
  enabled="{chatText.text.length > 0}"
  click='{model.send(chatText.text); chatText.text=""}'/>
```

Also I don't think there's anything wrong with a view component handling it's own view logic...